# how to edit comment within article's page - keep getting error about nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have typical article and comment blog format. It's a typical has_many/belongs_to, ie, the Guide's blog type.

However, I'm trying to edit the comment within the article, and I'm clueless about building the right form for this.

It's also in a partial which makes it more complicated for me.

Any help and/or educating me would be appreciated.

**Comment's model**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

**Article's model**

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :comments

    validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5} 

end
```

**Article's Show page**

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @article.comments %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

**Comment's _comment.html.erb page**

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>


<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_comment_path(@article, comment) %>
</p>
```

**Comment's _form.html**

```
<%= form_for([@article, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**Error**

It comes from Comment's `_form.html.erb` page in reference to this line: `<%= form_for([@article, @comment]) do |f| %>` ... and the error is: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` ...

**Articles Controller**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController


    def index
        @articles = Article.all 
    end


    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def edit 
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        #render plain: params[:article].inspect
        #@article = Article.new(params[:article])
        #@article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text))
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save 
            redirect_to @article 
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update 
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])

        if @article.update(article_params)
            redirect_to @article 
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end


    def show 
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy 
        @article = Article.find(params[:id]) 
        @article.destroy 

        redirect_to articles_path 
    end


    private 
        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
        end

end
```

**Comments Controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy 
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy 
    redirect_to article_path(@article) 
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please post controller action where you set `@article` and `@comment`.

Comment: Also, how are rendering that partial?

Comment: show your comment controller

Comment: @Gerry, mea culpa for such a late response. Have posted both `Articles` and `Comments` controller.

Comment: @Pavan, not sure what you mean by how I'm rendering the partial ... thought it was visible in Article's show page? I.e., `<%= render @article.comments %>` and `<%= render 'comments/form' %>` ... sorry for late response.

Comment: @lakhvirkumar, just added both `Articles` and `Comments` controller right now. Sorry for late response.

Comment: I mean, you a render a partial with `<%= render partial: 'file_name' %>` right? I want you to update the question with the file name where you putting the code of the partial and code as well.

Comment: @Pavan, that's what I was trying to explain in my earlier comment. I rendered it like this: `<%= render @article.comments %>` and like this: `<%= render 'comments/form' %>` ... I wasn't aware of other ways to render it. It's an area of confusion for me. The partial file's name is `_comment.html.erb` and its code is listed the post above. Please let me know if I misunderstood your question. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. In which file you have this `<%= render 'comments/form' %>`?

Comment: @Paven, it's in `Article's show.html.erb page` and it's in the post above.

Comment: I've added my answer which should resolve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

The error is due to `@article` and `@comment` being nil in the form. Since you are rendering the form with a partial, you need send variables to the partial as well

Change `<%= render 'comments/form' %>` to `<%= render 'comments/form', article: @article, comment: @comment %>`

and in the form have this `<%= form_for([article, comment]) do |f| %>`

Also in the `show` method of *articles controller*, you should define `@comment`

```
def show 
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

Comment: @Paven, this works, thank you. Wondering though if `@comment = Comment.new` is anti-pattern though? also, even though this solved this problem, the whole premise of this question was originally to do with editing the comment which brings up the same error, ie, `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` ... and therefore the comment can't be edited ... better off posting it as a separate question again?

Comment: @user273072545345 You can post it as another question if you want. Same applies for edit also. only difference is @comment will not be a new instance. It will hold a record(i.e, particular comment) like this `@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Also `@comment = Comment.new` is not anti-pattern here as the form is to add a new comment, `@comment` should should be a new instance of Comment. Hope you got it. I would appreciate an upvote and marking as correct answer. Glad to help!

Comment: @Paven, sorry for delay in accepting your answer. Was going to do that anyway since you solved this one. Will review and post it as a separate question tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: @Paven, also wondering why it was necessary to do it this way `<%= render 'comments/form', article: @article, comment: @comment %>`, since the `_comment.html.erb` form had this `<%= form_for([@article, @comment]) do |f| %>` ...

Comment: @user273072545345 partial files will not have access to instance variables defined in the methods direcly. You should pass them like that

Comment: @Paven, in other words, you have to always define the instance variables outside of the partial files in order to pass it since they don't have access to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146142/discussion-between-pavan-and-user273072545345).

Comment: @Paven, oy vey, just saw your comment in continuing in chat ... maybe tomorrow?